# How to setup flutter engine in linux for using software rendering

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-engine

I have a Flutter application that needs to be ported to a new platform, which uses Linux as its operating system. However, the OpenGL environment on the system is currently unavailable. After looking at the Flutter engine code, I know that Flutter engine can use software rendering for rendering. Can some guys advise me on how to configure this?

When I use the 'flutter run' command to run my project in the target platform, I get the result like this.
`[FATAL:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl_delegate.cc(57)]  Check failed: gl_version_string: The GL proc resolver's glGetString(GL_VERSION) failed.`
I have also tried running my project using 'flutter run --enable-software-rendering', but it doesn't seem to make any difference. The error persists, and it seems that the '--enable-software-rendering' parameter does not work on the Linux platform.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.